# How to lock Windows on sleep?

Tags: windows-7, login, sleep

After my Windows 7 returns from a hybrid sleep, it shows the desktop instead of the logon screen.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an option at your energy options. On the left side of the Window you can find something like "passwort on activation" or something. I only got a german Windows version so I cant tell you the correct name of the option. But there you can set a checkbox "password needed". 
After activation you will need to enter your password while waking from sleep mode.